# variable not defined! (python)

Tags: python

I have been trying to run my first full text adventure but whenever i run it it says that answer is undefined! please help. in case if you're wondering, here's the code

```
accept = input("would you like to play the game??")
if accept.lower() .split() == "yes":
    answer: str = input ("you wake up in a room with two doors in front of you. do you go to the left or the right?")
if answer.lower() .split() == "left":
    answer2 = input(" you enter the left door. you find a phone with a peice of paper attached to the wall with the phone\n there are two numbers on the peice of paper\n will you choose to call the first one or the second one")
```

Comment: I imagine `answer: str = input` is supposed to be `answer = input`?

Comment: Note that `accept.lower().split()` returns a list, so it will never be equal to the string `"yes"`. Also, please include the complete error traceback in your question.

Comment: It's because your first `if` statement is always false, and the `answer` variable is only defined within the scope of that if statement.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I was thrown off cause none of the other inputs had a type hint.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the condition did not meet the if statement's requirement, so yo never defined answer. It was the .split() that made it wrong:

```
accept = input("would you like to play the game??")
if accept.lower() == "yes":
    answer = input ("you wake up in a room with two doors in front of you. do you go to the left or the right?")
    if answer.lower() == "left":
        answer2 = input(" you enter the left door. you find a phone with a peice of paper attached to the wall with the phone\n there are two numbers on the peice of paper\n will you choose to call the first one or the second one")
```

You see, when yo have str.split(), python will return a list, not a string.
Have a look at this:

```
print("hello".split())
```

Output:

```
["hello"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is similar to this:

```
x = False
if x:
    answer = "yes"
print(answer)
```

Note how, because `x` is `False`, `answer` never gets defined and when Python reached the line where it needs to print `answer`, it will report the error.

You either need to define an `else` clause, or define the value up front, i.e.:

```
x = False
answer = "no"
if x:
    answer = "yes"
print(answer)
```

Or:

```
x = False
if x:
    answer = "yes"
else:
    answer = "no"
print(answer)
```

Whether you pick a default or an explicit alternative should depend on what makes more sense for your code, they are both valid ways of solving this. In your case, it depends on what you need to do if they player does not answer "yes".